# is there a better way to do this without reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set all of the properties of a class using the same function.  Currently I am using reflection to get all of the properties and looping through to set their values.  I know all of the properties, there is nothing dynamic happening.

Here is my code I am currently running in my constructor:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // retreive the value and set it
    property.SetValue(this, GetValue(field), null);
}
```

Is there way to do something similar without using reflection?

Comment: source code omits important aspect... where does field come from ? do you know the class or is this a function that should work with different classes ?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: why are you doing this in the constructor ? In the constructor you surely know what properties your class has ?!?

Comment: (1) Is the `GetValue(field)` actually a call to `property.GetValue(field)` or do you have an internal collection of hte field names?  (2) Other than that, this is impossible to answer without additional context.

Comment: GetValue is mapping the field name to a list of database item.  I created a method that handles this and it works great.  What I'm trying to get around is having to call this on each property individually (even though I know what they are it is tedious) and the properties change often.  I would like to be able to have one method that loops through each property like this.

Comment: Your doing this instead of setting each of the properties individually, right? So what are you trying to avoid: someone updating this class with a new property and not calling this method? Less typing (because there's a lot of properties)? Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I am aware of based on the information given here.

That said, it does beg the question what are you doing that would require you to do this?  Why do you need to iterate over all your properties in a loop anyway, how many do you have?

A bit more detail may prompt someone to give you a better solution.  For example, what are the properties doing? Are they connected to some underlying data that could be changed without using reflection?  Is having a bunch of discrete properties the way to go if you have a lot of them?

Comment: All of the fields are mapped to underlying data and used in a view.  The problem I am trying to avoid is allowing easy changing of properties (editing, deleting, adding) and since they all have the same value method constructor I was trying avoid updating code in many places for any property changes.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a property called (for example) Username and you want to map that to the field with the same name, and you want to avoid having to update the constructor if you make name changes to the property/field names.  Well the answer to your question is no I believe, you have to use reflection to do this.  That said, I'm not entirely sure its a wise route to go to save a bit of code updating.  How often are you changing field names?

Comment: I think I may have to set each property individually like you are saying.  I think the cost of updating the code will be less than the cost of reflection.  Performance is important.  I will have a lot of classes like this, so I'm trying to determine the best pattern to use.

Answer (score 1):

Um, maybe I'm misinterpreting what you are saying, but you said you know all the properties, why not just write a method to set them?

```
void SetValues() {
    this.Property1 = field1;
    this.Property2 = field2;
    this.Property3 = field3;
    this.Property4 = field4;
}
```

I suspect there is something missing from your question.

Comment: this is exactly what I want to do, just abstracted since my properties will change often and I need to run the same function get the value of each field.

Comment: @Victor - how are you declaring the properties - are they 'automatic' properties, or ones that have explicit underlying data?

Comment: @iandotkelly I'm not sure what you mean by 'automatic' properties.  they all have underlying data.

Comment: Automatic properties are those declared without some underlying variable or other data storage, so you can declare an int property and the compiler automatically creates a private member int for your class.  http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/12/04/c-3-0-features-automatic-properties.aspx

Comment: ok, thank you for the explanation.  they are all automatic properties.